# Tor is already running/won't open

Tags: 16.04, gnome-terminal, tor

Alrighty. So, I've checked out this [thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2145092) in Ubuntu forums. I've run the commands `killall tor` to ensure that tor wasn't just already running (which it was) and then `sudo /etc/init.d/tor start`. I get the notification

```
[ ok ] Starting tor (via systemctl): tor.service.
```

But then I don't see anything happen. I sit there for five minutes and tor doesn't open. Maybe I'm doing something wrong at this point, I don't know. So, after trying this, I try running command `tor` to see if that happens. Terminal spits this at me (I've included my input so as not to confuse anyone)

```
~$ tor
Dec 08 19:50:28.740 [notice] Tor v0.2.7.6 (git-605ae665009853bd) running on Linux with Libevent 2.0.21-stable, OpenSSL 1.0.2g and Zlib 1.2.8.
Dec 08 19:50:28.740 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Dec 08 19:50:28.740 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
Dec 08 19:50:28.744 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Dec 08 19:50:28.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv4 file /usr/share/tor/geoip.
Dec 08 19:50:28.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv6 file /usr/share/tor/geoip6.
Dec 08 19:50:28.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 0%: Starting
Dec 08 19:50:29.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server
Dec 08 19:50:29.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 80%: Connecting to the Tor network
Dec 08 19:50:29.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 85%: Finishing handshake with first hop
Dec 08 19:50:30.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 90%: Establishing a Tor circuit
Dec 08 19:50:31.000 [notice] Tor has successfully opened a circuit. Looks like client functionality is working.
Dec 08 19:50:31.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 100%: Done
```

After sitting here for another five minutes, still nothing. Again, maybe there's something I did wrong or need to do after I do this step, but I don't know it. If that's the answer, please just tell me which step I'm missing and stop reading now.

So, after this doesn't work, I ensure tor isn't running by using my friend `killall` and then I open up tor using my search thing (forget what it's called) and click tor. The little icon pops up and then disappears and tor never opens. I was able to use tor after I first installed it. I've tried reinstalling it but I never got it to work again. Is it possible that there's a config file somewhere that I screwed up? Anyway, any help would be appreciated. Thanks, sorry for tons of terminal output!

Answer (score 2):

The output you pasted from your terminal would seem to indicate that tor *is* running. Now you just have to use it! Did you set up a browser for that?

The Tor Browser will work for you if you haven't got it already. Configuring your browser use localhost:9050 as a SOCKS5 proxy also works, but just using tor as a proxy doesn't make a browser private/secure.

To verify that you're using tor, point the browser you think is configured to use it at https://check.torproject.org/. If you get a message that "the proxy server is refusing connections" or similar, it may mean that your browser is configured to use tor, but it isn't running. Otherwise the page will give you the good/bad news about whether you seem to be using tor.

Comment: So I have installed tor browser, but when I open it up, the app appears in my sidebar, blinks for a minute and then disappears. What do I do about that?

Comment: Sounds like it's crashing for some reason. If you run it without starting Tor first, do you see a modal dialog pop up saying it's connecting to the Tor network?

Comment: I used to but I don't get that anymore. That's when my problem started occurring.

Comment: What do you see when you try to start the Tor browser from a terminal? For instance, I can invoke mine (from the directory where I downloaded it) with `./Browser/start-tor-browser --verbose` to get more output. In my case, I see basically the output you posted above, as Tor sets up. How about you?

Comment: I installed Tor from the universe. Where would I go to run that?

Answer (score -1):

```
$tor
$ cat /var/lib/tor/ssh_hidden_service/hostname
like
3l5zstvt1zk5jhl662.onion

so is ok
```

#### Tor Nat Traversal

```
# install to server
$ apt-get install tor torsocks

# or in mac os
$ brew install torsocks

# bind ssh to tor service port 80
$mkdir -p /var/lib/tor/ssh_hidden_service/
$chmod 700 /var/lib/tor/ssh_hidden_service/

# vi /etc/tor/torrc
SocksPolicy accept 127.0.0.1
Log notice file /var/log/tor/notices.log
RunAsDaemon 1
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/ssh_hidden_service/
HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:1221
PublishServerDescriptor 0
$ /etc/init.d/tor stop;/etc/init.d/tor start

# or
$service tor start

# or
$tor --service start
$/etc/init.d/tor status
$cat /var/log/tor/notices.log
$ netstat -lntp|grep tor
$cat /lib/systemd/system/tor.service

$ cat /var/lib/tor/ssh_hidden_service/hostname
3l5zstvt1zk5jhl662.onion


# ssh connect from client
$ apt-get install torsocks
$ torsocks ssh login@3l5zstvt1zk5jhl662.onion -p 80
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Firstly, Mac OS and any other OS except Ubuntu are off topic on Ask *Ubuntu*. Secondly, I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about what this command (sequence) does. A plain command (sequence) is rarely considered an answer. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)